# show the existentce of ${E_n} $ where ${f_n(x)}$ uniformly converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose m($E$) < $\infty$ ,  {$f_n(x)$} are limited and measurable almost everywhere, and $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\dot =0$   a.s.

Show that there must be a sequence of subsets {$E_n$} , s.t. $E_n \subset E_{n+1}$ , $\lim_{n\to \infty}m(E_n)=E$ and  ${f_n(x)}$ uniformly converges to $0$ on every $E_n$

Comment: You can find the proof in many books (even on wikipedia). The name of this theorem is "Egorov-luzin"

Comment: @user657324 thanks, I've just learned this theorem.